# Symfony-2.7 and oracle11g exception when updating database

Tags: php, oracle11g, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have a Symfony 2.7 project mapped to an oracle 11g database, as I think every config is ok(cause I'v already test it with pgsql and mysql db and there's no problem):

In `php.ini` extensions, dll when I try :
`doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` command, I get this exception that I can't resolve since:

> Unknown database type mgmt_coll_queue_obj requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\OraclePlatform may not support it

[image: the commande exception screenshot]

Please help me to figure out cause I tried everything possible: wamp, xaamp, IIS, changing  my php version but the error still remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found myself the solution...
When I configured the *parameters.yml* file ( database connection ) I've use the **sysman** account but it seems to be forbidden to use it(that's why the exception occur as I think), to figure out, just use another account(**you should create it first and grant ADMIN privileges**). It's running perfectly now!